# pyaudio installation error: "linux/limits.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: python

```
Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-vn4pktw5/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-yky9xwed/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-6tVwKN/python3.5-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/_portaudiomodule.o
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix1_lim.h:160:0,
from /usr/include/limits.h:143,
from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed/limits.h:168,
from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
from /usr/include/python3.5m/Python.h:11,
from src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h:38:26: fatal error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
#include <linux/limits.h>
^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I already have `/usr/include/limits.h`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try installing the kernel headers? ```sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic```

Comment: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic/include already exist.

Comment: linux-headers-4.8.0-22    install
linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic   install
linux-headers-generic    install

Comment: AFAIK user-space code should use the `linux/limits.h` from package `linux-libc-dev` - the files from `linux-headers-generic` are for kernel-space programming only

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev`

Then use:

`pip install pyaudio`